# What is the default MIME type of an Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, mime-types

If [setType()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setType(java.lang.String)) is not called on an Intent, what is the default MIME type?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [the documentation for `getType()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getType()):

> Returns: If a type was manually set, it is returned; else null is returned.

Hence, the default type is `null`.